# Can anyone identify this spider? Found in Italy

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

My cousin found this spider at his place. He lives near Milan, Italy, in a small town. It's a humid region, around there the are a lot of fields but it is a 15 km from the city. It's still hot in these days. He told me that in the picture it seems a little bit too yellow. In reality it is more of an orange shade. He has never seen anything like that around there. Any clues?

[image: the misterious spider]

[image: the dimentions]

Comment: Is there a spider somewhere on the second picture? I can't see it!

Comment: No, it's just to give a rough idea of the dimensions

Comment: Oh ok! You might want to just state something like `about 6cm in diameter (legs included)` or something.

Comment: @Gitana Yes please give a number, we don't know the size of your hand.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the photo and the web it may be an orb-weaver spider of the family Araneidae.  Orb-weaver spiders get their name from the circular webs they spin.  It's possibly an *Araniella cucurbitina*, also known as a Cucumber spider, which are commonly observed hanging head down in it's web.  Several photos can be found at [eurospiders.com](http://eurospiders.com/Araniella_cucurbitina.htm).

Comment: If I understand well, the Araniella cucurbitina seems smaller than my cousin's spider. I read that it measures at most 1 cm, whereas the spider he found is several centimetres long

Comment: @Gitana Is your cousin maybe exaggerating a bit for dramatic effect? The perspective of the picture might be a bit confusing but "several cm" might be closer to 2 cm, with the body about 1 cm.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [marbled spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araneus_marmoreus). Araneus marmoreus, commonly called the marbled orb-weaver, is a species of spider belonging to the family Araneidae. It is sometimes also called the pumpkin spider from the resemblance of the female's inflated abdomen to an orange pumpkin.[2] It has a Holarctic distribution.